# How to avoid Response error: 429 Too Many Requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

One Spring boot application sends many calls in parallel to another and in one time i faced with 29 Too Many Requests
How can avoid it?

Comment: The obvious answer is to send fewer requests.

Answer (score 1):

You should stop spamming your server and rethink your architecture. The 429 status is not an error. It is more a hint to stop spamming:

> The 429 status code indicates that the user has sent too many
> requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting").

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585#page-3

Answer (score 1):

You need K8s with clustering of your micro service and to think how you want 
 to scale your pods horizontally.

On top of that you need to use a load balancer and maybe to use the ribbon + Hysterix + Feign client out of the stack of spring cloud solution.

And you also have too check that you don't receive too many auto-retry technical requests of your underlying HTTP client.

Answer (score 1):

Your application sends many calls in parallel to another, I unable to get what is another?,

If another is db call then you can increase connection size in db then you wouldn't be get in future.

or else if another is API call then you should go with batch statement it will helpful instead of parallel call.

Answer (score 0):

This is standard use case for Pub-Sub pattern. Use any message queue like, SQS, Kafka etc.
First spring boot instance should push messages to this queue. Another spring application (or any application) should poll messages at the rate suitable for it self.
Messages will be hold in the queue until app2 picks it up.